# How do i remove the content between two patterns on multiple lines using sed?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, scripting, scripting-language

This is the input

```
hai people<PATTERN>  we had
<PATTERN>a lot of fun<PATTERN>

writing scri pts
We will<PATTERN>
have more
<PATTERN>tomorrow<PATTERN>
Hurray!
```

Need to have

```
hai people<PATTERN>  we had

writing scripts
We will<PATTERN>
have more
Hurray!
```

For me the first pattern match removes using the following command

```
sed '/PATTERN/{n;/PATTERN/d}' filename
```

Comment: I don't get this. What are you exactly trying to do? Please elaborate more.

Comment: I need to remove the lines that begin with <PATTERN> and end with <PATTERN>. A explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -Pv '^<PATTERN>.*<PATTERN>$' input
hai people<PATTERN>  we had

writing scri pts
We will<PATTERN>
have more
Hurray!
```

using `sed` ,although its an overkill:

```
sed  '/^<PATTERN>.*<PATTERN>$/d' input
```